# Inserting a row into a Gridpane

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

## I'm trying to insert a row into a grid pane.

## How can I achieve this?

Further reading/information/effots:

I've been able to append the row with this:

```
    add.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            Peak thisPeak = new Peak();
            MenuPeak dispPeak = new MenuPeak(thisPeak);
            int row = 1+thisPeak.peakCount();
            //psMenu.addRow(1+row);
            psMenu.add(dispPeak.name,1,row,1,1);
            psMenu.add(dispPeak.retTime,2,row,1,1);
            psMenu.add(dispPeak.tol,3,row,1,1);
        }

    });
```

Which takes my original menu layout from

[image: Start]

to

[image]

I tried googling, some people suggested using an addRow.  I've tried a few variants (currently one is commented out in the snippet I provided.

This ends up just overwriting my buttons as seen:

[image]

I am ultimately wanting it to insert the row between the buttons as such (hard-coded the peak line):

[image]

Perhaps there is a better solution, but I found some success by re-adding the element buttons again, but this is producing some runtime errors yet is working?

```
    add.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            Peak thisPeak = new Peak();
            MenuPeak dispPeak = new MenuPeak(thisPeak);
            int row = thisPeak.peakCount();
            psMenu.addRow(1+row);
            psMenu.add(dispPeak.name,1,row,1,1);
            psMenu.add(dispPeak.retTime,2,row,1,1);
            psMenu.add(dispPeak.tol,3,row,1,1);
            row++;
            psMenu.add(save,1,row,1,1);
            psMenu.add(cancel,2,row,1,1);
            psMenu.add(okay,3,row,1,1);
        }

    });
```

Which did make this

[image]

But again, the run time error complained about adding duplicate children.

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentExcepti on: Children: duplicate children
>   added: parent = Grid hgap=10.0, vgap=10.0, alig nment=TOP_CENTER
>           at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:454)
>           at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.add(VetoableListDeco
>   rator.java:206)

EDIT:  The answer is correct and the exact implementation of my correction is:

```
    add.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            Peak thisPeak = new Peak();
            MenuPeak dispPeak = new MenuPeak(thisPeak);
            int row = 1+thisPeak.peakCount();

            psMenu.setRowIndex(save,row);
            psMenu.setRowIndex(cancel,row);
            psMenu.setRowIndex(okay,row);

            psMenu.addRow(row-1, dispPeak.name, dispPeak.retTime, dispPeak.tol);

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the save, cancel and ok buttons although they are already children of the `GridPane`. Instead just adjust the row of those children. Also `addRow` adds nodes to a row. It does not "insert" a new row. If you do not pass any nodes to the varargs parameter, the method simply does nothing (If you'd start the `Node`s of the peak in the first column, you could e.g. use `psMenu.addRow(row, dispPeak.name, dispPeak.retTime, dispPeak.tol);`):

```
@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

    Peak thisPeak = new Peak();
    MenuPeak dispPeak = new MenuPeak(thisPeak);
    int row = thisPeak.peakCount();

    // add new nodes
    psMenu.add(dispPeak.name,1,row);
    psMenu.add(dispPeak.retTime,2,row);
    psMenu.add(dispPeak.tol,3,row);
    row++;

    // adjust row of buttons
    GridPane.setRowIndex(save, row);
    GridPane.setRowIndex(cancel, row);
    GridPane.setRowIndex(okay, row);
}
```

Comment: Wow!!  I just figured this out too. I'm accepting this answer!  Thank you!  I was playing around a lot with it.  I found I got better behavior by setting the row index before adding the new items, just FYI.  I was using addrow to add my new peak and it was inserting after the buttons in the row